# How to put in a profile picture in django

Tags: python, django

im following [Add image/avatar to users in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396442/add-image-avatar-to-users-in-django) tip to have users upload their profile pictures, and to display the user's profile picture when a user log in.

[Adding profile picture to django user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197051/adding-profile-picture-to-django-user)

But for some reason, it comes with an error saying "Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields' attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form UserProfileForm needs updating."

Is there anyway i can directly modify the django.contrib.auth.models's User model so that i can add only the profile picture and have it displayed on index.html?

there is not a whole lot of information regarding this profile picture system.

and it's only been days since i started learning about django and python.

could anyone explain with examples, how i can achieve this?

Thanks.

(this is the forms.py that's implementing the tip above)

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model, login, logout

class UserSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Confirm Email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'username',
            'email',
            'password'
        ]
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email_qs = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if email_qs.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("This email has already been registered")
        return email



from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions
from .models import UserProfile


class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

    def clean_avatar(self):
        avatar = self.cleaned_data['avatar']

        try:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(avatar)

            #validate dimensions
            max_width = max_height = 100
            if w > max_width or h > max_height:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Please use an image that is '
                     '%s x %s pixels or smaller.' % (max_width, max_height))

            #validate content type
            main, sub = avatar.content_type.split('/')
            if not (main == 'image' and sub in ['jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'gif', 'png']):
                raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please use a JPEG, '
                    'GIF or PNG image.')

            #validate file size
            if len(avatar) > (20 * 1024):
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    u'Avatar file size may not exceed 20k.')

        except AttributeError:
            """
            Handles case when we are updating the user profile
            and do not supply a new avatar
            """
            pass

        return avatar
```

Comment: Please post your forms.py file

Comment: I think the problem is with the import of your "UserProfile" model, Please import your models correctly.

Comment: @Prateek what do you mean? this is the userprofile from models.py which is correct.

Comment: class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user   = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField()

Comment: You are using "from .models import UserProfile" where .models is not getting resolved and your model is not getting imported, I mean to say that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118003/discussion-between-prateek-and-mark-kang).

Comment: You need to create model  image field, add image field to Meta fields, then add to template, when user upload his image you get this from model with queryset.

Comment: @VolodymyrKirichinets could you elaborate more on that using an example of it? sorry, i cannot follow what you are saying as im relatively new to this environment.

Comment: @Prateek that is not only incorrect but completely irrelevant.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Okay, I feel the error is asking to add fields = ['avatar'] below the model = 'UserProfile'

Comment: Roseman what You mind?

Answer (score 4):

Example:
models.py:

```
class YouModel(models.Model):
    .............You field ................
    user_avatar = models.ImageField((upload_to="You/media/uploads", blank=True) # You need to configure media in settings.py
    ........... You fields ..............

class YouModelForm(ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = YouModel
        fields = ['user_avatar']
```

views.py:

```
from .models import YouModel, YouModelForm

def youfunc(request):
    youtemplate = YouModelForm()
    if request.method == POST:
        youform = YouModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if youform.is_valid():
           youform.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.You.url') # or other
    youquery = .objects.order_by('user_avatar').last()
    return render(request, "YouProject/YouHtml.html", {'youtemplate': youtemplate, 'youquery': youquery})
```

I tired to write. You need configure django and write first file upload from user. You can visit to my website and look and decide - this is what You want? my website http://www.webmamoffice.org/en and go to UperVote or http://www.webmamoffice.org/en/upervote