# Uploading image through an upload form to Django User profile

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to create a student register page that allows the student to upload a profile photo. I am using Django `User` model and a `StudentProfile` model that has a `OneToOne` relation with `User`. Here are my codes:

student\models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='student_profile/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

students/form.py:

```
from django import forms


class ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):
    profile_photo = forms.ImageField()
```

eLearning/views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm
from students.forms import ImageUploadForm
from students.models import StudentProfile

User = get_user_model()


def register_page(request):
    register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    photo_upload_form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    context = {
        "register_form": register_form,
        "photo_upload form": photo_upload_form
    }
    if register_form.is_valid():
        # print(register_form.cleaned_data)
        username = register_form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        first_name = register_form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        last_name = register_form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        email = register_form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = register_form.cleaned_data.get("password")

        new_user = User.objects.create_user(
            username, email, password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )

        if photo_upload_form.is_valid():
            user = username
            avatar = photo_upload_form.cleaned_data.get("profile_photo")
            new_user_profile = StudentProfile.objects.create(user, avatar)

        print(new_user)
    return render(request, "auth/register.html", context)
```

auth/register.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row my-4">
        <div class="col-5">
            <form action="" method="post" class="form-control">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ register_form|crispy }}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-control">
                {% csrf_token %}
                 <input id="id_image" type="file" class="my-2" name="image">
                {{ photo_upload_form|crispy }}
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am facing 2 problems:

1) The `ImageUploadForm` is not rendering on to `register.html`

2) A `StudentProfile` is not being created. `User` is being created fine.

I also tried replacing form with `ModelForm` for `ImageUploadForm` but I get a `NULL constraint` for `student_user` since Django doesn't what `user` for `StudentProfile` is.

I have been looking through Stack Overflow. All solutions are about how to upload a user image to Django admin but I haven't found anything that shows how to associate the uploaded image to User model during registration. Forgive me if this is a repeated question. Thanks.

Comment: Is this  `if photo_upload_form.is_valid():` validating correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `eLearning/views.py:`
the context you are passing to the html page the `_` is missing

```
 context = {
        "register_form": register_form,
        "photo_upload form": photo_upload_form
    }
```

This will be the reason for the ImageUploadForm is not rendering on to `register.html`

It's should be like

```
context = {
        "register_form": register_form,
        "photo_upload_form": photo_upload_form
    }
```

Comment: thanks! that was a silly mistake on my part. That fixed the rendering issue. Still no sign of studentprofile :(

Comment: can you provide the error string that you are facing?

Comment: I think you forgot to save user after creating the user `new_user.save()` and also for `new_user_profile.save()` when you check the validity, I'm not tested the code

Comment: I think yes because you are just creating an object of the user after checking the validity of a form

Comment: I tried adding .save() and it's still the same issue. Seems like if photo_upload_form.is_valid(): is not being executed

Comment: Hope this will help you [add-image-avatar-field-to-users-in-django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396442/add-image-avatar-field-to-users-in-django?answertab=active#tab-top)

Full example with html code [simple-django-image-upload-to-model-imagefield](https://coderwall.com/p/bz0sng/simple-django-image-upload-to-model-imagefield)

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. The real issue was with the register.html code. The submit button only worked for the register_form so the photo upload form was not validating, hence student profile entry was not being created. Here's the updated code:

eLearning/views.py:

```
from students.forms import ImageUploadForm
from students.views import upload_pic

     def register_page(request):
            register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
            photo_upload_form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

            context = {
                "register_form": register_form,
                "photo_upload_form": photo_upload_form
            }
            if register_form.is_valid():
                username = register_form.cleaned_data.get("username")
                first_name = register_form.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
                last_name = register_form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
                email = register_form.cleaned_data.get("email")
                password = register_form.cleaned_data.get("password")

                new_user = User.objects.create_user(
                    username, email, password,
                    first_name=first_name,
                    last_name=last_name,
                )


                upload_pic(request, photo_upload_form, username=username)

            return render(request, "auth/register.html", context)
```

students/views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse

from .models import StudentProfile
from .forms import ImageUploadForm

def upload_pic(request, form, username):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                User = get_user_model()
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                avatar = form.cleaned_data.get('profile_photo')
                new_user_profile = StudentProfile.objects.create(user=user, avatar=avatar)
                new_user_profile.save()
```

register.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row my-4">
        <div class="col-5">
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-control">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ register_form|crispy }}
                {{ photo_upload_form|crispy }}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

You have to make sure `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is inside your  tags or the image upload form will not get validated. I would also recommend adding an image validation method to your form.py. Something Sachin pointed out earlier: [image form and validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396442/add-image-avatar-field-to-users-in-django?answertab=active#tab-top). Hope this helps.