# Entry gets into the DB even if an exception is thrown

Tags: python, django

So I have a form which takes some input and a file field. I'm using a validator on the file filed to check for the size of the file. It is working well because I get the error on the page saying that the file is too large, but the entry still gets into the DB.

I don't know why this happens. I supposed that raising an exception would do the trick in my case, but it does not.
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .validators import validate_file_size

# Create your models here.

class CV(models.Model):
    solicitant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dataUploadCV = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    nume = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    prenume = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    emailContact = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    CV = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%d/%m/%Y', validators=[validate_file_size])
    rezolvata = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nume + " " + self.prenume + ": " + str(self.CV)
```

validators.py

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


def validate_file_size(value):
    filesize=value.size

    if filesize > 1:
         raise ValidationError("Fisierul poate avea maxim 5MB.")
    else:
        return value
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Oferta, CV
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

# Create your views here

def incarcarecv(req):
    context = {
        'title': "Incarcare CV | Best DAVNIC73"
    }
    if req.method == 'POST':
        try:
            nume = req.POST['nume']
            prenume = req.POST['prenume']
            telefon = req.POST['telefon']
            email = req.POST['email']
            cv = req.FILES['CV']
            try:
                if(req.user.is_authenticated):
                    cv_upload = CV(
                    solicitant=req.user,
                    nume=nume,
                    prenume=prenume,
                    telefon=telefon,
                    emailContact=email
                    )
                    cv_upload.CV.save(cv.name, cv)
                    cv_upload.full_clean()
                    cv_upload.save()
                    req.user.profile.cvuri.append(cv_upload.id)
                    req.user.profile.save()
                    messages.success(req, 'CV depus cu succes!') 
                else:
                    messages.error(req, 'Trebuie sa fii logat pentru a depune CV-ul!')
            except (ValueError):
                messages.error(req, 'Formularul nu a fost incarcat!')
                messages.info(req, 'Verifica daca esti logat!')
        except:
            messages.error(req, 'Nu ai completat corect campurile sau unul din ele este liber!')
            messages.info(req, 'Ai grija ca toate campurile sa fie completate si ca fisierul sa nu depaseasca 5MB!')
    return render(req, "../templates/pagini/incarcare-cv.html", context)
```

html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
            <div class="container container-centru">
                <h1 class="heading-contact">Incarca CV</h1>
                {% include 'partials/_alerts.html' %}
                <form action="{% url 'incarcarecv' %}" method="POST" class="form-contact"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputnume" class="email-contact">Nume</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nume" class="form-control" id="inputnume" aria-describedby="numeHelp" placeholder="Introdu nume">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputprenume" class="email-contact">Prenume</label>
                                <input type="text" name="prenume" class="form-control" id="inputprenume" aria-describedby="prenumeHelp" placeholder="Introdu prenume">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputtelefon" class="email-contact">Telefon</label>
                            <input type="text" name="telefon" class="form-control" id="inputtelefon" aria-describedby="telefonHelp" placeholder="Introdu telefon">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inputemail" class="email-contact">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="inputemail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introdu email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputcv" class="email-contact">CV</label>
                                <input type="file" name="CV" accept=".docx,.doc,.pdf,application/msword" class="form-control" id="inputemail" aria-describedby="CVHelp">
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-group-custom">
                                <input type="submit" value="Trimite" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-login-custom">
                                <input type="submit" value="Resetează câmpurile" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-reset-custom">
                        </div>                   
                </form>
            </div>
            <script src="{% static 'javascript/clearMessage.js' %}"></script>                  
{% endblock %}
```

So how can I make the post not enter the DB if the exception is thrown? Right now I get the error, but it is still entering the DB. (I can see it in the administration zone of django)

////edit: I deleted everything that was not about my problem from the code.
////edit2: added the HTML file

Comment: You are calling `save` before you call `full_clean` try and reverse the order. Typically you want to run your validation and make sure the model is clean before you attempt to commit it to the db.

Comment: Now I get an error for every value.

Comment: you need to get the data from the form not from the request directly

Comment: As an aside, look into forms and class-based views to make your code much shorter and less buggy.

Comment: @AKX thank you. I will, but for now I need to finish this project.

Comment: @WilliamBright I also added the HTML file if it helps you. I've reversed the order like you said and now I get an error every time.

Comment: @JohnSmith whats the error? By the way your logic is too complicated even for me to sit down and think about it without stopping everything

Comment: @WilliamBright the error saying that the file is too large.

Comment: isnt that what you're trying to do? Either way are you using a Django Form?

Comment: I'm not. filesize > 1 was for testing purposes. Now if I set a real value (5MB, for example) I get that error everytime. I set something like 99999999 and the file had only 1MB and I still get that.

Comment: try a new validator like the one here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35321718/7596388

Comment: @JohnSmith also checkout https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/ makes things much easier to work with

Comment: It's not that. I've observed that if I add a print statement inside the validator, it doesn't work if I reverse full_clean with save like you said. If I use it like it is now, it does work though.

Answer (score 1):

In Django, the typical workflow is to first run validators to verify that the data you are trying to commit into the database is "clean" and only then should one call `save()`. But due to some quirks calling `save` does not automatically clean the data.

so the workflow should be something along the lines of:

```py
...
cv_upload = CV(solicitant=req.user, nume=nume, prenume=prenume, 
               telefon=telefon, emailContact=email)
# call clean before saving as we only want CLEAN data in the DB 
cv_upload.full_clean()
# now that it is relatively clean with Django's validators and our custom validators
# go ahead and save it
cv_upload.save()
...
```