# Is there a way override DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE on one model field only

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a way to override the Django DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE default (2.5mb) on one model field only? I would like to keep the that max value the same everywhere except for one particular field, where it needs to allow for uploading of a much larger file size.

I have implemented [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9016664/11470136) which works well but I would rather not have to use this custom class for every file upload field in application. I would like to keep DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE at 2.5mb if possible.