# Problems with uploading large files in django

Tags: python, django

I have project with courses. Course contains videos that usually bigger that 100mb. But when i am trying to upload this file, it instantly redirects without any loading, and when i am opening the admin i can see the name of this video, but when i am trying to open, i am redirecting to the page with player that doesn't showing video. How i can upload large files?

models.py

```
class SectionVideos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='courses/course_videos',max_length=100)
    section = models.ForeignKey(CourseSections,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    preview_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='courses/course_videos_preview_images',null=True)
    short_description = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
```

Comment: This answer right here could help please have a look at it https://stackoverflow.com/a/2472426/11117929

Comment: Where is the view and other code from where this called?