# What does AWS_S3_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE do in django-storages

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

According to the documentation

AWS_S3_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE(optional; default is 0 do not roll over)
The  maximum  amount  of  memory  (in bytes) a file can take up before being rolled over into a temporary file on disk.

Can someone explain this a bit more? Is this a way I could throttle upload sizes? What does "being rolled over" refer to?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System memory is considered limited, while disk space is usually not (practically speaking).  Storing a file in memory is a trade-off where you get better speed of access, but use up more of your memory to do so.  Say you have a large file of 1GB, is it really worth using up so much memory just to access that file faster?  Maybe if you have a lot of memory and that file is accessed very frequently, but maybe not. That is why there are configurable limits like this.  At some point, the trade-off is not worth it.

"Rolling over" would refer to when the in-memory file has gone over the set limit, and then gets moved into file-on-disk.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.

Comment: One question though. How could I cap the size of an image so that if it was too big the upload would stop. I have a validator written in my models and forms but it reads the file first and then determines if the file is too big. Instead of "rolling over" could I end the transfer and send a warning?

Comment: @JustinShakergayen that is something I do not know.  You can see this question, which has various different answers for how to do this. 
 I'd recommend reading each of them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472422/django-file-upload-size-limit